# Defining a piecewise function f(x,y) in SageMath

Tags: sage, piecewise

I'd like to plot the following simple function of two variables in SageMath, but I am not
sure how to define a piecewise function of two variables in Sage.

[image: f(x, y) = sqrt((x-2)^2 + (y - 1)^2) if x < 2, abs(y - 1) if x >= 2]

The [documentation for piecewise functions](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/piecewise.html) basically does this only for functions of one variable. How do I define a piecewise function of two variables like the above?

Answer (score -1):

Here are two ways to plot the desired function.

First, a fast and simple way:

```
sage: f = lambda x, y: sqrt((x-2)^2 + (y - 1)^2) if x < 2 else abs(y - 1)
sage: p = plot3d(f, (-3, 5), (-3, 3))
sage: p
Launched html viewer for Graphics3d Object
```

Second, a more elaborate way taking into account the simple boundary for
the pieces of this function and the piecewise linear nature of one of the parts.

Define two functions for the two pieces:

```
sage: g = lambda x, y: sqrt((x-2)^2 + (y - 1)^2)
sage: h = lambda x, y: abs(y - 1)
```

Plot them on the appropriate domains, with different but nearby colors:

```
sage: G = plot3d(g, (-1, 2), (-3, 3), color='cadetblue')
sage: H = plot3d(h, (2, 5), (-3, 3), color='steelblue', threejs_flat_shading=True)
```

Note how we used flat shading for the one whose graph is piecewise linear.

Add the graphs of the pieces to get the graph of the function:

```
sage: K = G + H
sage: K
Launched html viewer for Graphics3d Object
```